# Maximum function nesting level exception when running 'php artisan make:widget'

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, php-7, laravel-artisan

I am getting a PHP Fatal Error exception when running *php artisan make:widget RecentNews*, after going through the installation steps as described [here](https://github.com/arrilot/laravel-widgets#Installation).

```
PHP Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting! in .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 698

PHP Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting! in .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php on line 115
```

Full command output can be found [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38956788/PHP%20Fatal%20error.txt).

Increasing the value of xdebug.max_nesting_level in the php.ini (to 500, f.e.) did not help. It then told me it reached its maximum function nesting level '500'.

*php artisan make:model test* runs without any issues.

I am running php 7.0.8-2+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 and using laravel 5.3.
The widget pack used (arrilot/laravel-widgets) can be found [here](https://github.com/arrilot/laravel-widgets).

What am I doing wrong? Or how can I solve this?

Comment: Please add some code :)

Comment: from https://github.com/illuminate/console/blob/master/GeneratorCommand.php : ` protected function parseName($name)
    {
        $rootNamespace = $this->rootNamespace();
        if (Str::startsWith($name, $rootNamespace)) {
            return $name;
        }
        if (Str::contains($name, '/')) {
            $name = str_replace('/', '\\', $name);
        }
        return $this->parseName($this->getDefaultNamespace(trim($rootNamespace, '\\')).'\\'.$name);
    }` you see it call's itself i guess getting  `$rootNamespace` fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in Laravel v5.3 and is fixed in v5.3.1.
See [this topic](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14950) for details.